# Accounts not merged

Tags: bug, android-app, merge-accounts

In my profile it shows two accounts for Magento.  I have no problem with it on the website, but in the mobile app, due to these multiple accounts, I am unable to view my profile content.

These multiple accounts existed from the day I had changed my associated email address (about 2 years ago). Can anyone help me to merge these accounts?

[image]

Comment: @DavidPostill no it's not. The accounts are already merged, one of them is deleted. The site still shows both for some reason, but the app shows only the deleted account, twice, so it's not possible to see the real one, that's a bug in the app.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then the OP should use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link

Comment: @DavidPostill still, not a dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard CV retracted